# gem Ransack custom search for only Year instead of full date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a Rails 5.1 application and a Ransack search form with a dropdownlist containing some database columns. One of the column is finish_date and has values in format eg "2007-12-31". In the input field I have to type exactly the full date to get a match but I want to change the behaviour that it accepts only the year as input value.

How can I pass in a custom predicate that transforms the input value from full date eg. 2007-12-31 to only year?

What I'm looking for is a Ransack equivalent for the sql query:

```
SELECT *
 FROM imagecapturing
 WHERE YEAR(finish_date) = 2007
```

My Ransack form:

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <%= f.grouping_fields(f.object.new_grouping) do |g| %>
    <%= g.condition_fields(g.object.new_condition) do |c| %>
      <%= c.predicate_select only: %i(cont not_eq eq) %>
      <%= c.value_fields do |v| %>
        <%= v.text_field :value %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "filter" %>
<% end %>
```

in my controller:

```
  @search = Imagecapturing.ransack params[:q]
  @imagecapturings = @search.result.page params[:page]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Ransacker:

You can write something like this in your model:

```
  ransacker :custom_years do |args|
    query = <<-SQL
      Year(finish_date)
    SQL
    Arel.sql(query)
  end
```

See also using [Ransacker on Ransack Wiki](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Using-Ransackers)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can accomplish the results you need using scopes.  You can see the test project I created here:
https://github.com/wmavis/so_rails_ransack

The documentation has an example of how to use scopes here:
https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/#using-scopesclass-methods

I added the following to my Imagecapturing model:

```
  def self.finish_year(year)
    where("strftime('%Y', finish_date) = ?", year)
  end

  def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
    %i(finish_year)
  end
```

(I had to use strftime because my test project was using sqlite, but you can change that to YEAR(finish_date) like you wanted)

In the view, I just use the search field named finish_year:

```
  <%= f.label :finish_year %>
  <%= f.search_field :finish_year %>
```

Let me know if you have any issues getting it working.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort answering and creating a test project. But I already have an existing form (with dropdown attributes) and I'm not sure how to integrate your solution to the existing form.